# Buying same item over and over - In App Purchase Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

i want to buy same item over and over but code gives me null pointer exception when try to buy second time.

Here is the code;

```
try {
        Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), "ucret", "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

        startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When this code script works again pendinIntent coming null.

We can ask to google if user has already purchased like above code

```
 inventory.hasPurchase(sku_id);
```

But I want to sell same item whenever i open the screen.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Google prevents users to buy same items. So if you do this, you must tell the google "let me". And this is named "consuming".

Here it's all consuming method

```
private void consumeBilling() {

    try {

        Bundle ownedItems = iInAppBillingService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);

        int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");

        if (response == 0) {

            ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");

            ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");

            ArrayList<String> signatureList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST");

            String continuationToken = ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

            for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {

                String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);

                //   String signature = signatureList.get(i);

                //    String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

                //    RDALogger.info("purchaseData " + purchaseData + " signature " + signature + " sku " + sku);

                RDALogger.info("purchaseData " + purchaseData);

                String purchaseTokenString = new JSONObject(purchaseData).getString("purchaseToken");

                int responsee = iInAppBillingService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), purchaseTokenString);

                RDALogger.info("Consuming response " + responsee);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        ErrorHandlers.handle(PaymentActivity.this, new HoustonWeGotAProblemException());
    }
}
```

PurschaseToken from purchaseData will go to this code

```
  int responsee = iInAppBillingService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), purchaseTokenString);
```

after these you told google, this item can be bought again.