# Buy same item over and over without consuming - In App purchase android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I have kept a donate tab and want to let the users buy the items over and over again. I have implemented a code but it lets the user buy the specific item only once. I have used managed products in play console for products.

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           if(billingClient.isReady()){
             SkuDetailsParams params=SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
             .setSkusList(Arrays.asList("purchase_aaa","purchase_bbb","purchase_ccc","purchase_ddd"))
             .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP).build();

 billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
         @Override
          public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
           if(responseCode==BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK)
        {
              loadProductToRecyclerView(skuDetailsList);
                  }
             else{
               Toast.makeText(Donate.this, "Cannot query product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                  }
                });
                }
                else
        {
                Toast.makeText(Donate.this, "Not ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

  @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
        if(purchases!=null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Purchased"+purchases.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's by design and cannot be changed, in-app managed products can only be purchased once.

If you want the user who has paid more to have more features enabled, you will have to create as many in-app managed products as levels exist.

If it is a game in which, for example, the user is consuming items then when he no longer has any, you consume the in-app product so he can buy it again.

Or you can also consume the product immediately after the purchase and keep track of how many he has purchased through your own means, an own server or perhaps through firebase, but this already means that you will have to implement a user authentication system for your app.

Consume a purchase:

```
ConsumeResponseListener consumeListener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, String purchaseToken) {

            }
        };
 String token = purchase.getPurchaseToken();
            ConsumeParams consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(token).build();
            billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, consumeListener);
```

Comment: I came across some answers on stack which wrote some method to consume the item, but couldn't understand it. Here's the link to it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045189/buying-same-item-over-and-over-in-app-purchase-android 
Could you please check it out? @Lluis Felisart

Comment: That link uses the deprecated AIDL billing service, new projects shoud use the billing library.  I edited my answer with some code for consume a purchase.

Comment: I was using the new version but had some problems and went back to the old one which has int responseCode instead of BillingResult billingresult. I tried your code but I get errors following String token and so on.

Comment: Can you please add an answer which is compatible with my version? @Lluis Felisart

Comment: Your code uses the billing library, the same of my consume code.

Comment: Please check the edits. I have uploaded an image @Lluis Felisart

Comment: purchase is the variable that contains the Purchase object you want to consume.but it seems that your code does not yet have the part that makes the purchases, Sorry but I can not help more, I will not write the code for you. This is the main reference https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview